# Java graphic image

Tags: java, image, graphic

Hey I am adding the following image in the Jpanel: [msu-footprints.org/2011/Aditya/map.jpg](http://msu-footprints.org/2011/Aditya/map.jpg)

**And then adding polygon**:

```
int[] x = new int[]{65, 122, 77, 20}; 
int[] y = new int[]{226, 258, 341, 310}; 
g.setColor(Color.RED); 
g.drawPolygon(x, y, x.length);
```

The polygon should coincide with building GER but is a little bit offset. My proff says the co-ordinates are okay. Is there anything wrong with how I put the image position? –

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem including some context to your question and probably more *well formatted* code. Maybe it's me, but I'm finding this question quite confusing and incomplete.

Comment: The image might have a margin of a pixel or two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If painting directly to the top level container (JFrame), then the
coordinate space will be wrong, the content pane is actually
offset, taking into account the frame's border and menu bar.

This will occur if you override any of the frame's `paint` methods OR use the `getGraphics` method.

[image: JFrame showing coords of origin and (offset) content]

Create a custom component (extending from something like `JPanel`) and override it's `paintComponent` method and render the image and rectangle directly to it.  The coordinate space will then be correct (top, left corner will be 0x0)

Comment: A picture paints a 1000 words.  That one even more so.  If the text started with *"If painting directly to the top level container (JFrame), then the coordinate space will be wrong, the content pane is actually offset.."* it could almost be a 'canonical answer' to that aspect of TLC rendering.

Comment: I made 1 further edit.  If you do not like it, please roll back.  OTOH 1. it just reads better like this (IMO). 2. People can look at the [edit revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13078040/revisions) if they are that interested in 'credits'. ;)