# Java and Windows 8 Toolbar

Tags: java, windows, graphics, titlebar

I'm working on a program in Java and I'm having trouble with the titlebar in W8. For some reason the co-ords (0,0) are up and hidden in the titlebar. If I want to draw something at (0,0) I have to translate the Graphics object to (0,10) to get it to appear.

I currently have:

```
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Config.WIDTH + 10, Config.HEIGHT + 10);
        g.translate(0, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(fonts.getFont(0));
        g.drawString("FPS: " + scr.fps, 0, 0);
```

This works, however I'm wanting to remove `g.translate(0, 10);` incase this line ends up causing problems later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with Windows 8, but the fact that you've overridden `paint` of a top level container.

The frame border is painting within the bounds of the window.

A frame has a content pane which should be used to layout the contents or perform custom painting.

Instead of overriding `paint` of the top level container, create your self a custom component (extending from something like `JPanel`) and override it's `paintComponent` method.

You can then either add it to the frames content pane or replace the frames content pane

Check out...

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [Java graphic image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077858/java-graphic-image/13078040#13078040)
- [How can I set in the midst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734069/how-can-i-set-in-the-midst/13734319#13734319)
- [How to get the EXACT middle of a screen, even when re-sized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457237/how-to-get-the-exact-middle-of-a-screen-even-when-re-sized/13460914#13460914)
- [Graphics rendering in title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313084/graphics-rendering-in-title-bar/13316131#13316131)

For further explanations

Comment: I was painting onto a JPanel that was painting onto a JFrame, hence why (0,10) was the top left and not (8,38). Turns out the font that I was using for some reason wants to start drawing -10 pixels above where it should. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: That's because fonts want to start rendering at the ascender line (`FontMetrics#getAscent`). Take a look at [Working with Text APIs, Measuring Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html) and [`FontMetrics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) for more details