# Java Swing Jframe has less size than configured

Tags: java, swing

I want to place some elements inside a JFrame by setLocation(x, y) but my frame is not the size I expect.

The size of my JFrame is 600 x 400 but when I run the app it looks like a JFrame of about 550 x 350.

I would like to understand why this happens, even if there are better ways to implement it.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

My code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Example");
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);
      mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      mainFrame.setSize(600, 400);
      mainFrame.setLayout(null);
      mainFrame.setResizable(false);

      JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
      p1.setSize(100, 100);
      p1.setLocation(0,0);
      p1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
      mainFrame.add(p1);

      JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
      p2.setSize(100, 100);
      p2.setLocation(500,300);
      p2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
      mainFrame.add(p2);
  }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: A frame's visible content size is the frame size minus the frame's decorations insets.  So you viewable area will be `600x400 - frameDecorationInsets`, and this will be variable (even across the same platform).  Instead, you should be looking at the size of the parent panel ... but arguably, you shouldn't be using `null` layouts, you should be relying on things like `JComponent#getPreferredSize` and `JFrame#pack` to provide suitable hints about how best you want the window to be sized by default

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to get the EXACT middle of a screen, even when re-sized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457237/how-to-get-the-exact-middle-of-a-screen-even-when-re-sized/13460914#13460914); [How can I set in the midst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734069/how-can-i-set-in-the-midst/13734319#13734319); [Java graphic image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077858/java-graphic-image/13078040#13078040); [Graphics rendering in title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313084/graphics-rendering-in-title-bar/13316131#13316131)

Comment: __never-ever__ do any manual sizing or locating that's the exclusive task of a suitable layoutManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A frame's visible content size is the frame size **minus** the frame's decorations insets.

So your viewable area will be `600x400 - frameDecorationInsets`, and this will be variable (even across the same platform).

Instead, you should be looking at the size of the parent container, for example

[image]

*Note, I'm running on MacOS, which has a different frame decoration then Windows, but this concept will still work on both ... and you get resizability*

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        private JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        private JPanel p2 = new JPanel();

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(null);

            p1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            add(p1);

            p2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            add(p2);
        }

        @Override
        public void doLayout() {
            super.doLayout();
            p1.setSize(100, 100);
            p1.setLocation(0, 0);

            p2.setSize(100, 100);
            p2.setLocation(getWidth() - p2.getWidth(), getHeight() - p2.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 400);
        }
    }
}
```

## But...

Arguably, you shouldn't be using `null` layouts, you should be relying on things like `JComponent#getPreferredSize` and `JFrame#pack` to provide suitable hints about how best you want the window to be sized by default, for example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            JPanel p1 = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(100, 100);
                }
            };
            p1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            JPanel p2 = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(100, 100);
                }
            };
            p2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;            
            add(p1, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
            add(p2, gbc);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(600, 400);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: null layouts always get downvotes - you knew it ;)

Comment: @kleopatra Which is why there is an example of the "right" way do it ;) - answer the "question", then answer it "right" :P

Comment: what's not at the top isn't read so doesn't exist ;)